# "Reducir algo de/del X % a/al Y%": how to express percentages in Spanish?

Tags: gramática, sustantivos, artículos, locuciones, matemáticas

I am not sure if an article is required before percentages in Spanish. Are both examples below correct?

- Él redujo la pobreza de 60% a 36 %.
- Él redujo la pobreza del 60% al 36%.

Comment: No es "de 10 % a 20 %", sino "del 10% al 20%", es decir,    de [el 10 %] a [el 20 %].

Comment: Um, did you try googling to find some authentic sentences?  Or, did you try looking at linguee.com?  You can get a quick view of what's common with either of those methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see. According to [the Spanish *Gramática*](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=bGgtigfzRmXgZDio):

> Las expresiones fraccionarias que designan porcentajes (*treinta por ciento*, *ochenta por ciento*) son nominales.

This is, the group "X por ciento" acts as a whole as if it were a noun. Hence they must comply with the standard rules for nouns:

- They can be preceded by a definite or indefinite article:

  > **Un** treinta por ciento de los trabajadores se sumaron a la huelga.
- They admit adjectives:

  > El setenta por ciento **restante** acudió al trabajo con normalidad.

If you want to omit the article you need to stick to the [standard rules](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/8552/12637) for omitting the article before nouns, but how do you generalize the concept of "X por ciento"? Usually a percentage is an amount of something ("30 por ciento *de algo*"). Generalizing the concept of "30 por ciento" would imply referring to that percentage for *any thing* that can be expressed as a percentage, or maybe it would imply to talk about the percentage itself and not about the percentage of something.

Given that this is not the case, you definitely need the article in your example, as you are talking about a specific percentage of a specific property (poverty). So the proper sentence is the second one:

> Él redujo la pobreza del 60% al 36%.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! "reducir la pobreza *del* 60% *al* 36%"  sounded strange to me because in Portuguese we say "reduzir a pobreza de / *dos* 60% a / *aos* 36%" (ie, the alternative is to use a masc plural article). One more small difference between both languages.

Comment: In my question, I meant X and Y as amounts, eg "reducir la pobreza de 60% a 36%". As you said that the percentage *can* be preceded by an article, I am not sure if that article-less example would be correct. Would it?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista no, it wouldn't as you are talking about specific levels of a specific property (poverty), so you need to include the article.

Comment: Thanks! I have simplified my question and you could simplify your answer to make it easier to understand for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Both forms are fine but they have different implications.

I agree with Charlie about the article based on the fact that a percentage is a part of a whole

> Él redujo la pobreza de *[el]* 60% a *[el]* 36% [de los habitantes del país]

Buth the prepositions **de** and **a** also denote origin and destiny. In other words, these prepositions are equivalent to **desde** and **hasta**. So:

> Él redujo la pobreza **de** 60% **a** 36%   (*desde* 60% *hasta* 36%)

I admit this may be arguable because as a percentage is a part of a whole, this form also warrants an article:

> Él redujo la pobreza desde *el* 60% al 36%

But the preposition **de** is also a quantifier:

> Íbamos a una velocidad **de** 150km/h

Thus, with quantities we can say:

> El coche nuevo puede acelerar **de** 0km/h **a** 100km/h en dos segundos

We may now think this is a different case; however we may be tempted to say

> El coche nuevo puede acelerar desde *los* 0km/h hasta *los* 100km/h